# Do laravel crons can use the same database connection if executed at the same time on laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, laravel, database, cron, laravel-5.8

Ι have setup 2 laravel cronjobs that both run run queries to the database:

```
$schedule->command(MyCommand::class,['param', '1'])->daily('1:30');
$schedule->command(MyCommand::class,['param', '2'])->daily('1:30');
```

And the command is the following:

```
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class MyCommand extends Command
{
   $signature = "my:command --param {param}"

   public function run()
   {
      $sql = DB::select(^some_heavy_query^);
      // Do other stuff
   }
}
```

Both crons run in a single server with the following crontab:

```
* * * * * php artisan schedule:run > /home/ubuntu/cron.log 2>&1
```

Ιn this case does both executions of `MyCommand` can share the same database connection if are run on the same server on the same cron process?

What I am asking if on each execution the Laravel's Database driver will use the same PDO instance and the same connection socket to the database if both commands run at the same time at the same server.

Comment: Hi Dimitrios, short answer: Yes, it can. You even can test this on your local machine if you want with the following command: `php artisan schedule:work` => https://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling#running-the-scheduler-locally

Comment: So in order to further clarify both commands will share the same connection socket with the database and the same PDO connection object right?

Comment: I would believe so as the same php artisan schedule:work command would execute both commands. But i think this is a very high level question, not that many developers would be able to answer. And that leads me to my next conclusion why is that so important? In big applications you would have many different operations that would tax the database and there no one asks exactly this question.

Comment: Then reason why is because I have timeouts on simple queries and I want to exclude that the timeout is because commands share the same socket.